# How to create controller with own model without route in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I have `App.HomeRoute`, which doesn't has model, but elements on this page must have their own models. 
I use `render` helper for render these elements, but how I must to load models for they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the design is correct, but you can "load" other models using `setupController` method in your route.

```
App.YourRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        // set other properties
        var a = this.store.find("modelA");
        controller.set("a", modelA);
        var b = this.store.find("modelB");
        controller.set("b", modelA);
    }
});
```

Now in your template just use them

```
{{each a}}
    <div>{{id}}</div>
    etc...
{{/each}}
```

Comment: So, I'm not sure the design is correct too, therefore I answere about it ;)
I have usual App.HomeRoute, App.HomeController, App.HomeView and template `home`. They are don't have nothing special.
Template `home` has helpers for render specific views:

    {{render "twitter"}}
    {{render "carousel"}}

How I must load models for twitter and carousel if routes for their do not exist?

Comment: I wrote about it, just use `controller.set("twitter", this.store.find("twitter"))` and in your controller/template you can use `twitter` property. For example you can use `{{render "twitter" twitter}}`